# Extract 10 digits after decimal point and apply rounding up to 3 postions

Tags: c#, sharepoint, decimal, rounding

I want to implement logic of rounding up to 3 decimal positions after rounding.

If the value of decimal place 1 – 3 is equal to 000 (regardless of the whole number), and the value of the 4th thru the 10th decimal place is greater than 0, the 3rd decimal place in the display will round up.

example:

```
1.1230000000  --> 1.123
1.1230010000  --> 1.123
1.1230600000  --> 1.124
1.0000010000  --> 1.001
1.0003000000  --> 1.003
5.0000001234  --> 5.001
```

looking forward

Comment: First, that's a pretty weird "rounding" routine. Second, your example seems to be wrong or I don't understand it. Based on your description you should get 1.124 from 1.1230010000, not 1.123 as in your example.

Comment: TToni, you are right...i dont know how I made that mistake. We need to do this jsut for display purpose as we cannot display long numbers.

Comment: So can you think of any logic for this?? i know its weird but i hv to do it as requirement... !

Comment: What data type are you using - float, double, or decimal?  Depending on the type, a routine that depends on small differences in decimal values would be impossibly flaky due to problems representing decimal fractions in binary.

Comment: 1.00030000 to 1.003? Or 1.001?

Comment: Random ways to cook the numbers requires random code.

Comment: As I read the question, the intention is simply to handle values greater than X and less than X.001 as a special case by treating them as X.001. Although not mathematically accurate, I can understand that if someone wants to make sure that fractional numbers are not treated as actual integer values for some reason.  If that is the case, then by my understanding 1.123001 should be 1.123, and 1.12306 should be 1.123, since both are greater than 1.001.  I'm guessing that 1.1236 should be 1.124, since I assume normal rounding rules apply in all other cases.

Comment: Implement this where? Calculated column, dvwp, custom code? Details man, details!

Comment: TToni, it should be 1.00030000 to 1.001 ...you are again rt. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Math.Ceiling(myNumber*1000)/1000;
```

should do the trick for positive numbers. Test if you get the desired behavior for negative numbers (not given in your examples). If not, use Floor instead of Ceiling for negatives.

Comment: hey TToni, Want to ask one more thing. while I am dividing a double number by another double number, how can i retain the same amount of decimal places after division?

Comment: I am sorry. My question is that i want to keep the number after division with exactly 10 decimal places after decimal point.

Comment: Is Math.Round(a/b,10) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a sharepoint person, but I have general languages experience.

not `Math.ceil()` use js `Int()` or whatever `int()` function you have.
ceil() regardless of frac value != 0 always moves up to next integer. parseInt chops off the frac part, which is what he was really trying to do. I can't find any sharepoint API references on msdn.
I am basing this on the JavaScript/ecmascript 262 5.1 spec.
if you want number of digits like 5 digits, it's

```
Function truncateDigits(Double n, Integer numdigits)) 
    return Int(Math.Power(10,numdigits)*n)/Math.Power(10,numdigits);
EndFunction
```

but be aware that floating point has a problem with even repeatedly adding or subtracting 0.1 and you get wild results due to floating point error. to work with financials, you should use a decimal data type if there is one, the decimal data type if the language provides it does not have this problem. otherwise, you can simulate fixed-point fractional by looking at a large integer type and faking a decimal point in the middle or where you want it and calculating accordingly. display would require that you create your own display routines. but it would be fast and limited in abilities (no trig funcs, powers you would have to write on your own based on integers). you would need to come up with your own arithmetic routines, because normal ones assume the decimal point in the wrong place.